# Problems with sort -gr using bash

Tags: bash, list, sorting, numbers

I want to sort a list numerically in descending order:

```
$cat b.txt
a -0.51
c 0.62
m -0.3
z -0.004
b -0.44
```

To do it, I used "sort -gr -k 2" in order to obtain:

```
$sort -gr -k 2
c 0.62
z -0.004
m -0.3
b -0.44
a -0.51
```

But the command sorted it alphabetically. I think that the command considers that it is only one column. I tried to use -nr but it doesn't sort well the float numbers.

Comment: The list IS sorted in decreasing order form column 2: 0.62 > -0.004 > -0.3 > -0.44 > -0.51

Comment: Also, what alphabet do you use that `c z m b a` is in alphabetical order?

Comment: No, I expected the result I wrote but the result was not ordered numerically. The result was: z m c b a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using gnuplot, I verified that

```
plot "<sort -k2gr file" using 0:2 with lines
```

really sorted the numbers numerically in descending order. What order did you expect?

[image: Graph]

Comment: You needed gnuplot to verify this?

Comment: @ScottHunter: No, but I thought the OP might.

Comment: I don't obtain that result... Maybe it's because my bash version is not updated?

Comment: Doesn't the input file contain hidden characters? Try inspecting it with `xxd`.

Comment: I found the problem! For some reason, my computer interprets `.` as `,`. If I use `,` for decimals it works.

Comment: Using `LANG=en_US` the problem is fixed.

Comment: Hmm, I've never tried to sort using non us encoding.

Answer (score 0):

This sorts just fine:

```
echo 'a -0.51
c 0.62
m -0.3
z -0.004
b -0.44' | sort -rn -k 2
c 0.62
z -0.004
m -0.3
b -0.44
a -0.51
```